# Running cron job with large data

Tags: r, amazon-ec2, cron, bigdata

I'm running RStudio on AWS and I have a cron job setup to run every 5 minutes. The only issue is that I'd like to have this job use two rather large data files (one is a 1.3gb .rds, the other is a 2.2gb .feather) to perform some calculations, but the readRDS/read_feather takes too long.

Is there any way to execute a cron job with data cached, or is there another way to solve this issue (the job should finish on time before the next 5 minute mark) without resorting to, say, an infinite while loop executing this function in the global environment?

Thanks!

Comment: What’s wrong with an infinite loop? Have you tried the fst package instead of RDS/feather? What’s the disc speed on AWS?

Comment: I'm not 100% sure on the disc speed on AWS but it just feels generally slow. I'll have a look at the fst package, so thanks for the suggestion. As for why I'm not a big fan of an infinite loop launched in the global environment, it's more that I feel that there "should" be a better solution.

Comment: If your HD is not fast enough to read the 3.5 GB in time, then you will have to keep the data in memory. You could split-up the data and put it into Redis. But then you would have to retrieve the data and reassemble it before processing. This will probably be faster than reading from disk, but  at the cost of doubled memory consumption during execution.

Comment: I'll probably use your suggestion for an infinite loop, it's working quite well. Thanks!